# sscanf error: cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*'

Tags: c++, string, arduino, char, constants

I'm trying to extract two numbers separated by a space from a string and save them as two ints. For example:

```
if input_string = "1 95" then:
servo_choice = 1
input_number = 95
```

Code:

```
String input_string = "";
int input_number = 0;
int servo_choice = 0;

input_string = Serial.readString();
sscanf( input_string, "%d %d", &servo_choice, &input_number );
```

The IDE gives me this error:

```
exit status 1
cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int scanf(const char*, ...)'
```

Edit: I guess

```
input_number = input_string.substring(1,5).toInt();
```

Actually works and does what I want. I'd still like to know how to get sscanf to work if possible.

Thanks for any replies in advance..

Comment: You're compiling in C++, in which case the tag is also wrong. Please update the tag and the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to convert your `String` into a `char` array with [toCharArray](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToCharArray) and pass that to `sscanf`. Something like that (not tested though)

```
int buffer_len = input_string.length() + 1;
char buffer[buffer_len];
input_string.toCharArray(buffer, buffer_len);
sscanf(buffer, "%d %d", &servo_choice, &input_number);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `String` is a class, not a basic type. That means that you need a method to convert / return a pointer to char if you want to use it in a `sscanf`. That method exists and it's called `c_str()` .

So, your line has to be:

```
sscanf( input_string.c_str(), "%d %d", &servo_choice, &input_number );
```